# The Equation $-2x^2 +kx -2 = 0$ has $2$ different real solutions. Find the set of possible values of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, discriminant

I found what I think the discriminant is $k^2-16k = 0$ but I am unsure where I should go from here to answer the question itself, please help.

Comment: Since there are 2 different real solutions, you want the discriminant to be greater than $0$, i.e. the solution to $k^2 - 16k > 0$ is the solution to your question.

Comment: How would I get the solution to k^2−16k>0 , is it just simple rearranging or is there some other method I dont know about?

Comment: $k\lt 0$ or $k>16$.  To be positive, $k(k-16)$ must have both factors negative, or both factors positive.  The factors will both be negative when $k < 0$, and both factors will be positive when $k>16$.

Comment: $k(k-16) \gt 0$ what does it mean for sign of $k$ and $k-16$?

Comment: There are two ways to solve a quadratic inequality, and both require finding its roots. One is by factorization, as the above. Another is to imagine the graph of $f(k) = k^2-16k$.

Comment: @FlynHartman: factor it then use interval method

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you mean to write $-2x^2 +kx -2k = 0$ or $-2kx^2 + kx-2 = 0$?  Because the discriminant of the equation in your title is $k^2 -16$, and not $k^2-16k$.

Comment: Um... it should be noted the discriminant is $k^2 -16$ and not $k^2 - 16k$.  Although AmWhy's suggestion that the equation could have but $-2x^2 + kx - 2k=0$.  That would make for a more interesting and illuminating solution.

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ has two distinct real roots if the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac>0.$

In this case we have the quadratic $-2x^2+kx-2$, so $b=k$, $a=-2$ and $c=-2$.

Thus for the discriminant we have $b^2-4ac=k^2-16=(k-4)(k+4)>0$, so $k>4$ or $k<-4$.

Comment: To add: the last step of this solution uses the fact that if $(k-4)(k+4)$ is greater than $0$ then either both factors are positive or both factors are negative. If they are both positive then $k-4>0$ and $k+4>0$, and the solution of this pair of inequalities is $k>4$. The case where both factors are negative is similar. If this is not making sense, try sketching the graph of the discriminant.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you made a mistake in thinking that $"4(a)(c)"$ under the radical included $k.$

We know $\quad -2x^2 +kx -2\quad  =\quad 2x^2 -kx +2 = 0\quad $ solved for x is

\begin{equation}
x=
\frac{k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4(2)(2)}}{2(2)}=\frac{k\pm\sqrt{k^2-16}}{4} 
=\frac{k\pm\sqrt{(k-4)(k+4)}}{4}
\implies k\ge 4 \lor k\le -4
\end{equation}

because if $\quad-4 < k < 4\quad$ then the radical yields an imaginary number.

Comment: Um.... what if $k < -4$?  Also you forgot to have 2 *distinct* solutions we *can't* have $k^2 -16 =0$.   $-4<k < 4$ yeilds a negative under the radicand.  but $k = \pm 4$ yields $0$ (equally unacceptable) and $k < -4$ or $k > 4$ will both yield a positive under the randicand.  Both acceptable.

Comment: @ fleablood I saw it almost immediately but called away by a family member before I could finish the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The equation in $ax^2 + bx + c$ form for $-2x^2 +kx -2$ is $a=-2,b=k,c=-2$ so the discriminant is $b^2 - 4ac = k^2-4(-2)(-2) = k^2 -16$.  (Not $k^2-16k$....  and not $blah = 0$; just the $blah$ itself; the discriminant is a value-- not a statement *about* the value-- the value itself)

So we need to have $k^2 -16 > 0$.

The means $(k+4)(k-4) > 0$.  So either both $k+4$ and $k-4$ are both positive or both negative.  If they are both positive then $k + 4 > 0$ and $k > -4$ and $k -4 >0$ and $k >4$.  So $k > 4 > -4$ or in other words $k > 4$.  If they are both negative then $k+4 < 0$ and $k < -4$ and $k-4 < 0$ so $k < 4$..  so $k < -4 < 4$ or in other words $k < -4$.

So either $k > 4$ or $k < -4$.

Or we could do:  $k^2 -16 > 0$ so $k^2 > 16$ so $|k| > 4$ so $k < -4$ or $k > 4$.